# python subprocess calling the local interpreter instead of the linked one

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, interpreter

I am attempting to execute a function within a Python script as a subprocess using its own interpreter, specified in the subprocess.run() call. This interpreter may include packages not present in my local Python environment. When I debug the file, errors occur due to these missing libraries in my local python instead of the one linked in the command. Am I misunderstanding something?

```
try:
    proc = subprocess.run(
        [
            r'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe',
            r'C:\subprocess_python\my_file_subprocess.py',
            str(self.x), str(self.y), str(self.z)
        ],
        capture_output=True,
        check=True
    )
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as proc_err:
    print("An exception occurred in the subprocess: \n ", proc_err)
    print("stdout : \n", proc_err.stdout.decode())
    print("stderr : \n", proc_err.stderr.decode())
    exit(1)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "local interpreter" vs. "linked interpreter"? Those aren't standard terms, and it's unclear what you mean by them.

Comment: "When I debug the file, errors occur due to these missing libraries in my local python instead of the one linked in the command." I'd need to see proof of that. I suspect you are misinterpreting whatever error message you are getting, or that you aren't correctly identifying which packages `my_file_subprocess.py` requires.

Comment: @chepner: It's also possible they did something terrible like define a `PYTHONPATH` environment variable (which is used by *all* Python's that launch) rather than installing things properly per-interpreter.

Comment: @ShadowRanger by linked one the one whose path is in the subprocess\.run() command and by local i mean the local IDE where I am calling this subprocess.run() file

Comment: @chepner I am pretty confident about the packages ,  whenever I run the file my_file_subprocess.py , it works just fine with all the packages it needs are available in the system interpreter , but whenever I dubug while calling it form the subprocess , it only complains about the package missing which is not available in the local intepreter that I am using to call this subprocess.run command

Comment: @Novice_Developer You may be confident, but we are not. If you have installed the packages in the correct virtual environment and you are using the correct Python interpreter to execute `my_file_subprocess.py`, the problem you are describing should not happen. You need to provide a [mcve], demonstrating what module your script requires, proof that it has been installed in your virtual environment, and the exact import error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sys.executable` to determine what's the path of currently ran interpreter.

Comment: sys.executable returns the path for the linked one but pkgutil.iter_modules() returns the path of the local interpreter

Comment: `pkgutil.iter_modules()` is a generator that list of `ModuleInfo` objects, not a single path